# Failed to install haskell-src-exts-1.16.0 on OSX 10.9.5

Tags: macos, haskell, ghc, cabal

My env:

- ghc 7.8.3 from http://ghcformacosx.github.io/
- OSX 10.9.5
- cabal 1.20.0.3 (directly from ghc for mac osx)

I did `cabal install alex` and `cabal install happy`. cabal binary path was confirmed to be added to my $PATH as `$(HOME)/Library/Haskell/bin/`.

`cabal install haskell-src-exts` emitted the following compiling error:

```
[19 of 22] Compiling Language.Haskell.Exts.InternalParser ( dist/build/Language/Haskell/Exts/InternalParser.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/Exts/InternalParser.o )

templates/GenericTemplate.hs:104:22:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’
                with actual type ‘Happy_GHC_Exts.Int#’
    In the expression:
      (n Happy_GHC_Exts.<# (0# :: Happy_GHC_Exts.Int#))
    In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                   a case alternative:
      (n Happy_GHC_Exts.<# (0# :: Happy_GHC_Exts.Int#))
    In a case alternative:
        n | (n Happy_GHC_Exts.<# (0# :: Happy_GHC_Exts.Int#))
          -> (happyReduceArr Happy_Data_Array.! rule) i tk st
          where
              rule
                = (Happy_GHC_Exts.I#
                     ((Happy_GHC_Exts.negateInt#
                         ((n Happy_GHC_Exts.+# (1# :: Happy_GHC_Exts.Int#))))))

templates/GenericTemplate.hs:115:23:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’
                with actual type ‘Happy_GHC_Exts.Int#’
    In the expression:
      (off_i Happy_GHC_Exts.>=# (0# :: Happy_GHC_Exts.Int#))
    In the expression:
      if (off_i Happy_GHC_Exts.>=# (0# :: Happy_GHC_Exts.Int#)) then
          (indexShortOffAddr happyCheck off_i Happy_GHC_Exts.==# i)
      else
          False
    In an equation for ‘check’:
        check
          = if (off_i Happy_GHC_Exts.>=# (0# :: Happy_GHC_Exts.Int#)) then
                (indexShortOffAddr happyCheck off_i Happy_GHC_Exts.==# i)
            else
                False

templates/GenericTemplate.hs:117:30:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Happy_GHC_Exts.Int#’
                with actual type ‘Bool’
    In the expression: False
    In the expression:
      if (off_i Happy_GHC_Exts.>=# (0# :: Happy_GHC_Exts.Int#)) then
          (indexShortOffAddr happyCheck off_i Happy_GHC_Exts.==# i)
      else
          False

templates/GenericTemplate.hs:119:13:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’
                with actual type ‘Happy_GHC_Exts.Int#’
    In the expression: check
    In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                   a pattern binding:
      check

templates/GenericTemplate.hs:212:14:
    Pattern bindings containing unlifted types should use an outermost bang pattern:
      (sts1@((HappyCons (st1@(action)) (_))))
        = happyDrop k (HappyCons (st) (sts))
    In an equation for ‘happyMonadReduce’:
        happyMonadReduce k nt fn j tk st sts stk
          = happyThen1
              (fn stk tk)
              (\ r -> happyGoto nt j tk st1 sts1 (r `HappyStk` drop_stk))
          where
              (sts1@((HappyCons (st1@(action)) (_))))
                = happyDrop k (HappyCons (st) (sts))
              drop_stk = happyDropStk k stk

templates/GenericTemplate.hs:219:14:
    Pattern bindings containing unlifted types should use an outermost bang pattern:
      (sts1@((HappyCons (st1@(action)) (_))))
        = happyDrop k (HappyCons (st) (sts))
    In an equation for ‘happyMonad2Reduce’:
        happyMonad2Reduce k nt fn j tk st sts stk
          = happyThen1
              (fn stk tk)
              (\ r -> happyNewToken new_state sts1 (r `HappyStk` drop_stk))
          where
              (sts1@((HappyCons (st1@(action)) (_))))
                = happyDrop k (HappyCons (st) (sts))
              drop_stk = happyDropStk k stk
              (off) = indexShortOffAddr happyGotoOffsets st1
              (off_i) = (off Happy_GHC_Exts.+# nt)
              ....
Failed to install haskell-src-exts-1.16.0
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
haskell-src-exts-1.16.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: For the record, this affected me in ubuntu 15.10 as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be [known](https://github.com/haskell-suite/haskell-src-exts/issues/60) [issue](https://github.com/haskell-suite/haskell-src-exts/issues/64). If I understand it correctly, you just need to update `happy`

ADD: [Here](http://ro-che.info/articles/2014-03-08-happy-alex-ghc-7.8.html) is detailed description of the issue

Comment: Thanks for the complete reference. It turned out update happy did the trick. In my case, there was a soft link /usr/bin/happy -> /Library/Haskell/bin/happy, which was an old version that I didn't notice. Thus I reorder my PATH as $(HOME)/Library/Haskell/bin : ${PATH} and everything went fine.

Answer (score 0):

What we did to counter this issue was to install `happy` and `alex` each, separately in cabal sandboxed mode.
Then, we took the binaries and copied them over and everything was cool....

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure if had the same path issue as I was. There was an older version globally-installed happy in my system which shadowed my locally-installed latest happy. I'm not sure why there was an globally-installed one, though.