# stack install hlint ghc-mod fails

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

i wanted to build a haskell enviroment using stack ,and it's ok when "stack setup" to install the ghc8 but i failed when i run cmd "stack install hlint ghc-mod " ps: i read the article  from http://www.stephendiehl.com/posts/vim_2016.html

the error log:

```
While building package haskell-src-exts-1.17.1 using:
  /root/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/setup-Simple-Cabal-1.24.0.0-ghc-8.0.1 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0 build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
Process exited with code: ExitFailure (-11)
```

Comment: What is the full log? Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26098486/failed-to-install-haskell-src-exts-1-16-0-on-osx-10-9-5

Comment: @Sridhar Ratnakumar  yes,you re right ,i install and update happy and the problem solved